# How can I make _super() using the parent objects context?

Tags: ember.js

```
App.CurtainView = Ember.View.extend
  name: "CurtainView"
  getName: ->
    console.log @get("name")

App.ButtonView = App.CurtainView.extend
  name: "ButtonView"
  getName: ->
    # Do something
    @_super()
```

Returns on console:

```
ButtonView
```

...but I expect:

```
CurtainView
```

I guess this is a context issue - how can I make _super() using the parent objects context?

Comment: You're overriding the name, so IMO this is the expected behavior here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't completely get your goal. This behavior is the same as you would expect with Ruby language, but indeed differs from what you would obtain with Java *(assuming you would redefine the `name` attribute in `Button` subclass)*...

In fact, you have to be aware of the way the Ember's object model is implemented to better understand the behavior you get:

```js
App = Ember.Application.create();

App.CurtainView = Ember.View.extend({
  name: "CurtainView",
  getName: function() {
    console.log(this.get("name"));
  }
});

App.ButtonView = App.CurtainView.extend({
  name: "ButtonView",
  getName: function() {
    this._super();
  }
});

var c = App.CurtainView.create(),
    b = App.ButtonView.create();

console.log(c.getName.toString());
console.log(b.getName.toString());

c.getName();
b.getName();
b.getName.apply(c);
```

The `_super` call applies by default to the object on which the current function has been called.

You could override this default behavior by calling `getName` through `apply` or `call`, and passing the appropriated target. But it seems pretty weird to me...

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/wythe/)

Comment: Thanks for having a look at my issue. I indeed have a Java background and it looks like I don't know how to achieve my final goal, which is: Having a play()-method in App.CurtainView which does some animations using this.$(). My App.ButtonView also has a play() method, also using this.$(), but now of course App.CurtainView never gets animated, because its this.$() doesn't point to the right template anymore. How would you achieve that? (Right now I'm using this.get("parentView").play())

Comment: I think you poined the thing in your last sentense: The relation between your two entities is rather 'have' than 'is', so building a composition of views seems more appropriated than a hierarchy of inheriting view classes. Seems to be the right direction...

Comment: Okay, that would be a way to go. But how do I inform lots of views that something just happened (let's say my video fired the "ended"-event and up to five views have to do something about it)? Shall I loop over this.get("childViews") and call their end()-function? Or shall I consider an event-based system (while I didn't get Em.Application.create({ customEvents: {...} }); to work...)? Or shall I build a video controller with an isPlaying-property (though I couldn't find an easy way to make my views react to a controller...). Which way would you choose?